# How to count data in a column based on another column separately?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframe like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

I want to count the two numbers of df1 separately in df2, the correct answer like:

```
No   Amount
1    3
2    2
```

Instead of:

```
No   Amount
1    5
2    5
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter `df2` for values that are contained in df1['a'], then apply `value_counts`.  The rest of the code just presents the data in your desired format.

```
result = (
    df2[df2['a'].isin(df1['a'].unique())]['a']
    .value_counts()
    .reset_index()
)
result.columns = ['No', 'Amount']
>>> result
   No  Amount
0   1       3
1   2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply find `value_counts` of second df and `map` that with first df i.e

```
df1['Amount'] = df1['a'].map(df2['a'].value_counts())
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'a':'No'})
```

Output :

```
    No  Amount
0   1       3
1   2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

In pandas 0.21.0 you can use set_axis to rename columns as chained method.  Here's a one line solution:

```
df2[df2.a.isin(df1.a)]\
    .squeeze()\
    .value_counts()\
    .reset_index()\
    .set_axis(['No','Amount'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
   No  Amount
0   1       3
1   2       2
```